# Where to register postcss plugin in react app

Tags: reactjs, plugins

In order to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-modules-values-replace) package, I think I need to register it. I've already installed it with npm.

I created the project with `npx create-react-project my-project`. I tried putting in the requirements into index.js like so...

```
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import postcss from 'postcss';

postcss([ require('postcss-modules-values-replace', require('postcss-calc'))])
```

But I got an error `Cannot statically analyse 'require(...,...)` and it looks like it's because I'm supposed to do something with webpack but I don't see any `webpack.js` files in my project so I'm not sure how to register the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Place it before other plugins:

```
postcss([ require('postcss-modules-values-replace'), require('postcss-calc') ]);
```

create **postcss.config.js** file and define the plugins

```
module.exports = (ctx) => ({
   plugins: [
     require('postcss-modules-values-replace')({fs: ctx.webpack._compiler.inputFileSystem}),
     require('postcss-calc'),
  ]
});
```

Comment: when does this file get ran?

Comment: A more detailed response would be appreciated (Where am I supposed to place it?  I don't have a place for declaring plugins. Am I supposed to import postcss.config.js somewhere, etc...